# How to add a number to multiple variables at once?

Tags: python

So this isn‘t really a question, I was just wondering a way to optimize code to make it easier to read with less code.

Basically, my code looks like this:

```
 if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
    first_circle_pos_2 += 3
    second_circle_pos_2 += 3
    third_circle_pos_2 += 3
    fourth_circle_pos_2 += 3
```

I was wondering if instead of using four lines of code to add three to each one, I could add three to each one in a single line. Also, if my code looked like this:

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
    first_circle_pos_2 += 6
    second_circle_pos_2 += 12
    third_circle_pos_2 += 18
    fourth_circle_pos_2 += 24
```

Would there be a way to add the four numbers to the four variables in one line, something like

```
first_circle_pos_2, second_circle_pos_2, third_circle_pos_2, fourth_circle_pos_2 += 6, 12, 18, 24
```

That is just an example of what I mean by adding to multiple variables in one line.

Comment: How about putting them in a list or a dictionary then using a loop? Repeated actions/operations is a good indicator that it should be done in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work with assignment, but not with such operations. I'd just use a list and change values in a for loop or some map, etc., etc..

So, instead of doing first_circle_pos, second_circle_pos and etc. you want to use lists, because it's a lot simpler. For example:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
    for i in range(len(circle_pos)):
        circle_pos[i] += 3
```

And if values are differ but predefined you can go with:

```py
offsets = (6, 12, 18, 24)

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    for i in range(len(circle_pos)):
        circle_pos[i] += offsets[i]

# or in this case
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    for i in range(len(circle_pos)):
        circle_pos[i] += (i + 1) * 6
```

Or your circle might be an object so it will be passed by a reference in the for loop so you can drop the index and range:

```py
class Circle:
    position = 0


circles = [Circle(), Circle(), Circle()]

print([c.position for c in circles])  # 0 0 0

for circle in circles:
    circle.position += 3

print([c.position for c in circles]) # 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first example, instead of using 4 different variables for your circle position, I'd use a list of values.

This enables you to use list comprehension, which is a nice one-liner:

```
circle_pos_2 = [0, 0, 0, 0]

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    circle_pos_2 = [x+3 for x in circle_pos_2]
print(circle_pos_2)

# Output:
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

For your second example, list comprension is also an option, utilizing `zip`:

```
circle_pos_2 = [x+y for x, y in zip(circle_pos_2, (6, 12, 18, 24))]
print(circle_pos_2)

# Output:
[9, 15, 21, 27]
```